# Citing a HAL INRIA document in the prescribed format with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am reading a research report *[CENTAUR: the system](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00075774/document)* that is stored in the [HAL INRIA](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/) archive. The preamble mentions how this research report is to be cited, as shown below.

[image: Required citation style]

I would like to cite this research report in the design document of an open source AGI research project *[RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org)* (to which I am contributing in a small way). However, I am unable to cite the research report in the prescribed manner. With the following markup:

```latex
%
% Minimal *.tex file
%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./000_cs.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

%
% *.bib file entry in ./000_cs.bib
%

@techreport{borras-clement-despeyroux-incerpi-kahn-et-al:2006,
  author      = {Patrick Borras, and Dominique Clement, and Thierry Despeyroux, 
                 and Janet Incerpi, and Gilles Kahn, and Bernard Lang, 
                 and Valerie Pascual},
  institution = {INRIA},
  month       = {may},
  note        = {inria-00075774},
  number      = {RR-0777},
  title       = {CENTAUR: the system},
  url         = {https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00075774},
  year        = {2006}
}
```

the closest result I am getting is as shown below.

[image: non-conformant citation]

Specifically, the questions I have in mind are:

- Is there a separate bibliography entry type for research reports that renders `[Research Report]` instead of `Tech. rep.`? I thought of using `@misc`, but intuitively that did not seem to be the correct approach.
- How would I ensure that the first five authors are listed? Is there a specific package that I would need to use?

I believe that a possible workaround would be to make a manual `\bibitem` entry in a `{thebibliography}` environment (as shown in [this Overleaf tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex)), but I would very much prefer to achieve this result with BibLaTeX instead, especially since the RefPerSys design document already makes use of BibLaTeX.

I would appreciate any pointers to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` provides the `type` fields for technical reports, and you can add the line

```
type = {Research Report},
```

in the `bib` file. Thus, the entry in the `bib` file will look like:

```
@techreport{borras-clement-despeyroux-incerpi-kahn-et-al:2006,
  author      = {Patrick Borras, and Dominique Clement, and Thierry Despeyroux, 
                 and Janet Incerpi, and Gilles Kahn, and Bernard Lang, 
                 and Valerie Pascual},
  institution = {INRIA},
  month       = {may},
  note        = {inria-00075774},
  number      = {RR-0777},
  title       = {CENTAUR: the system},
  type        = {Research Report},
  url         = {https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00075774},
  year        = {2006}
}
```

For the list of names, you can add the options `minbibnames=5` and `maxbibnames=5`, to print only the first 5 names (values of `minbibnames`) in a list with more than 5 names (values of `maxbibnames`, `minbibnames` should be less or equal than `maxbibnames`).

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear, minbibnames=5, maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}
```

[image]